# SQL - view very slow or doesnt return any results

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I am new to SQL and struggling with very slow view, it should return newest event for specific person. This view doesnt use PERSON entity (but it could). The relation Person->Event is oneToMany.

**Structure**

```
PERSON:
ID
NAME

EVENT:
PERSON_ID
EVENT_DESC
EVENT_TYPE
IDX
```

Below is very slow view, which works too slow (indexes on PERSON_ID and ID are created but it is still very slow)

`select * from V_CURRENT_EVENT_FOR_PERSON where person_id = 123456`

**View to be changed (too slow)**

```
create or replace force view "V_CURRENT_EVENT_FOR_PERSON" ("PERSON_ID", 
    "EVENT_DESC", "EVENT_TYPE") as 
select * from (SELECT EVENT.PERSON_ID            AS PERSON_ID,

    EVENT.EVENT_DESC AS EVENT_DESC,
    EVENT.EVENT_TYPE     AS EVENT_TYPE

  FROM PERSON_EVENT_DATA EVENT
  WHERE EVENT.ID =
    (SELECT EVENT2.ID
    FROM PERSON_EVENT_DATA EVENT2
    WHERE EVENT2.PERSON_ID = EVENT.PERSON_ID
    GROUP BY EVENT2.PERSON_ID,
      EVENT2.IDX,
      EVENT2.ID
    HAVING EVENT2.IDX =
      (SELECT MAX(EVENT3.IDX)
      FROM PERSON_EVENT_DATA EVENT3
      WHERE EVENT3.PERSON_ID = EVENT2.PERSON_ID
      )
    ))
```

**I tried to change it to:**

```
create or replace force view "V_CURRENT_EVENT_FOR_PERSON" ("PERSON_ID", 
    "EVENT_DESC", "EVENT_TYPE") as 
select * from (SELECT EVENT.PERSON_ID            AS PERSON_ID,

    EVENT.EVENT_DESC AS EVENT_DESC,
    EVENT.EVENT_TYPE     AS EVENT_TYPE

  FROM PERSON_EVENT_DATA EVENT order by EVENT.idx desc

 ) where rownum = 1
```

But here `select * from V_CURRENT_EVENT_FOR_PERSON where person_id = 123456` never retures any results because of the `rownum = 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, the following should do what you want:

```
select person_id, event_desc, event_type
from (
  select person_id,
         event_desc,
         event_type, 
         row_number() over (partition by person_id order by idx desc) as rn
  from person_event_data
) t
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Works twice as fast, thanks. I wrapped it in a VIEW. How it works in practice? When I do select * from V_CURRENT_EVENT_FOR_PERSON where person_id = 123456... It searches all events for all person and then applies condition for person_id or it only searches events for person 123456?

Comment: @michealAtmi: check the execution plan. I would assume Oracle pushes the condition `where person_id = ` into the view and does not evaluate this for all rows. But only the execution plan will show you that.

Comment: New problem happens: When I do paged (10 elements per page, qyery about page2) query like: select p.* from person p left outer join V_CURRENT_EVENT_FOR_PERSON vv on p.id = vv.person_id where rownum > 10 , then nothing is returned..

Comment: @michealAtmi: `where rownum > 10` will **never** return anything. See the manual for details: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/pseudocolumns009.htm#SQLRF00255